# Removing session Id in a cookie in PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP.
To remove a session I found this code.

```
$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}
session_destroy();
```

To remove cookie I thought I just had to set the expire parameter negative like below.

```
setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000)
```

Is there a reason for having all parameters here?

Comment: I had to look back into old [OWASP information](https://web.archive.org/web/20130115191154/https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet#Proper_Deletion), but it was part of their recommended practices. Setting the time to negative might not do anything if the system time is incorrect, as the browser's reference will be too (this is mentioned in the OWASP info). Plus, PHP's own information says that `Cookies must be deleted with the same parameters as they were set with.`, so it depends on the cookie use.

Comment: Then is it just good practice but no difference?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete your cookie, there is no special dedicated function provided in PHP to delete a cookie.  A very simple way of doing this is to deduct a few seconds from the current time.

before, i have made a cookie, which name is 'cart',

```
setcookie('cart', 'Indomie Noodle', time() + (86400 * 15), "/");
```

Clear/delete cookie syntax :

```
setcookie(name, time() - 3600);
```

and let's deleting the cart cookie

```
setcookie("cart", "", time() - 3600);
```

if this method still doesn't work, please comment below.. Good luck dude!

Comment: Im not sure you read the question well enought... the OP knows how to do this, they said as much in the question with a very similar example. The OP is asking about the first example they show and asks of _that example_ "Is there a reason for having all parameters here?".